# New event count on each day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Events which has 2 columns `dt` (Date) and `event`. I am trying to get the new event count for each day. For e.g. if the event appeared today and tomorrow, then it should only be counted for today (as it is show for the first time) and should be excluded from tomorrow's count.

```
+------------+-------+
| dt         | event |
+------------+-------+
| 2019-02-01 | u1    |
| 2019-02-01 | u2    |
| 2019-02-01 | u3    |
| 2019-02-01 | u4    |
| 2019-02-01 | u1    |
| 2019-02-02 | u5    |
| 2019-02-02 | u1    |
| 2019-02-02 | u6    |
| 2019-02-02 | u4    |
| 2019-02-03 | u8    |
| 2019-02-03 | u9    |
| 2019-02-03 | u6    |
+------------+-------+
```

I'm trying to get the below output:

```
+------------+-------------------------+
| dt         | count(distinct c.event) |
+------------+-------------------------+
| 2019-02-01 |                       4 |
| 2019-02-02 |                       2 |
| 2019-02-03 |                       2 |
+------------+-------------------------+
```

The query I am using is:

```
with cte (dt,event,rnk) as
(
select dt, 
event,
row_number() over (partition by dt order by event) as rnk
from events order by event
)
select e.dt, count(distinct c.event) from events e left join cte c
on  e.event <> c.event where e.dt = c.dt
group by 1;
```

But I am not able to filter out the already appeared event from the previous day. I believe something small is missing. The result from my query is:

```
+------------+-------------------------+
| dt         | count(distinct c.event) |
+------------+-------------------------+
| 2019-02-01 |                       4 |
| 2019-02-02 |                       4 |
| 2019-02-03 |                       3 |
+------------+-------------------------+
```

I am not sure if LEAD / LAG function can help solve the issue.
Also is there a way that I could achieve this without using any joins.

Table creation and insertion queries:

```
create table events (dt Date, event varchar(5));

insert into events values('2019-02-01', 'u1');
insert into events values('2019-02-01',  'u2');
insert into events values('2019-02-01',  'u3');
insert into events values('2019-02-01',  'u4');
insert into events values('2019-02-01',  'u1');
insert into events values('2019-02-02',  'u5');
insert into events values('2019-02-02',  'u1');
insert into events values('2019-02-02',  'u6');
insert into events values('2019-02-02',  'u4');
insert into events values('2019-02-03',  'u8');
insert into events values('2019-02-03',  'u9');
insert into events values('2019-02-03',  'u6');
```

Comment: I believe `2019-02-03` count should be only 2, because u6 already on day 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to find when is the first day the event appear.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/02143d/2)**

```
WITH ranks as (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by event order by dt) as rn
    FROM events
) 
SELECT dt, COUNT(event)
FROM ranks
WHERE rn = 1 
GROUP BY dt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|         dt | count |
|------------|-------|
| 2019-02-01 |     4 |
| 2019-02-02 |     2 |
| 2019-02-03 |     2 |
```

Comment: @Nick dont delete is a different aproach and OP can learn from it, I first thought doing something like that until realize OP was using new version of MySql and can use row_number()

Comment: Erm, both solutions require the 'new' version

Comment: With @Strawberry solution as well mine is definitely not required.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for older versions: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=12ba0196cf90994d3c9d853ac62405fe

```
CREATE TABLE events
    (`dt` varchar(10), `event` varchar(2))
```

```
INSERT INTO events
    (`dt`, `event`)
VALUES
    ('2019-02-01', 'u1'),
    ('2019-02-01', 'u2'),
    ('2019-02-01', 'u3'),
    ('2019-02-01', 'u4'),
    ('2019-02-01', 'u1'),
    ('2019-02-02', 'u5'),
    ('2019-02-02', 'u1'),
    ('2019-02-02', 'u6'),
    ('2019-02-02', 'u4'),
    ('2019-02-03', 'u8'),
    ('2019-02-03', 'u9'),
    ('2019-02-03', 'u6')
```

```
SELECT dt, COUNT(*) total FROM
(SELECT event, MIN(dt) dt
      FROM events
      GROUP BY event) x
GROUP BY dt
```

Actually, the subquery is all you need; the rest can be handled in application code.